# Как отобразить значения коллекции IEnumerable модели в стандартном View

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! У меня есть модель цветок, которая отображается во View, как вывести значения коллекции IEnumerable Flowers, то есть значения из модели цветы в стандартном View?

```
введите код здесьМодель цветок
     [DisplayName(@"Цветок")]
public class Flower : FlowerEntity
{
    public Flower()
   {
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// Номер 
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"Номер ")]
    public virtual int Number{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Название
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"Наименование")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
    /// Цветы
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"Цветы")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<FlowerMember> Flowers { get; set; }
}

   Модель цветы
   public class FlowerMember 
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Название
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = @"Наименование")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", Name);
    }
}
```

если я создаю свой шаблон в DisplayTemplates для вывода коллекции

```
     [UIHint("мой шаблон")]
     public virtual IEnumerable<FlowerMember> Flowers { get; set; }
```

это не работает, так же как и в случае без UIHint в представлении не выводится коллекция Flowers

Что нужно сделать в ASP MVC 3, чтобы вывести элементы данной коллекции во View, а также как посчитать их количество и тоже отобразить во View посчитанное количество элементов коллекции?

Comment: можете немного поподробнее рассказать о своем коде? Не очень понятно несколько моментов. 

1. Почему у вас все члены классов виртуальны?
2. Что такое Flower и FlowerMember?
3. Что такое поле Number в классе Flower?
4. Что вы вообще хотите получить на представлении?

Comment: 1. потому что должен использоваться полиморфизм и значение полей модели берется из БД.
2. Flower это основной мой класс, основная модель, а FlowerMember это вложенный класс в Flower, вложенная модель
3. Поле Number это просто число они выводятся на представлении, поля Number и Name считываются из БД
4. Мне нужно получить поле Name класса FlowerMember и отобразить его на представлении, т.е. поле коллекции Flowers, а также посчитать количество элементов коллекции и тоже вывести его на представлении

Comment: 1. Реализацию вещей, которые заложены в базовых классах моего проекта, данные вещи реализовывал не я, просто модификатор virtual должен быть, а также для чтобы соблюдались принципы ООП
2. Да эта вложенная сущность. Данная сущность много где будет использоваться в моих других представлениях, необходимо чтобы это была коллекция IEnumerable, используется чтобы было понятно из каких элементов состоит модель и что отбражается в представлении.

Comment: 3.Number это просто число, не число элементов в коллекции в его смысл вдаваться не нужно 
 4.Да правильно, это мне и нужно, только всего должно выводиться в виде поля в представлении, т.е. быть полем класса, и в представлении отображаться справа

Comment: хорошо. И последний вопрос - вы, наверное, используете Entity Framework?

Comment: Storage самописный, бд Oracle, EntityFramework не используется

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что до конца понял ваш замысел, тем не менее. Если вам нужно отобразить именно то представление, о котором говорилось  в комментариях к вопросу, то по сути моделью для него должен служить даже не какой-либо из классов, приведенных вами вше, а нечто следующее:

```
public class FlowerModel
{
   public string FlowerName {get; set; }

   public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

А отображать все это в представлении примерно так:

```
@model IEnumerable<FlowerModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Всего</th> 
    </tr> 
    @foreach(var flower in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@flower.FlowerName </td>
            <td>@flower.Count</td> 
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```

Или даже вместо модели использовать вот такое:

```
IDictionary<string, int>
```

Возможно, я что-то не понял, но для данного представления ваша модель Flower   совершенно не подходит

Comment: ладно хорошо, а как будет тогда выглядить представление, если помимо полей int и string, будет поле IEnumerable, из которого нужно получить Name, используя UIHint? при том как это вывести, используя стандартное представление, а не customное?

Comment: а зачем в модели нужно поле IEnumerable, если из него требуется только одна строка, вытаскиваемая рефлексией из атрибута? Вам не жалко гонять впустую с сервера на клиент целую коллекцию ради одной только строки?

Comment: мне требуется получить не одну строку я привел пример просто мне требуется получить из FlowerMember две строки Name и Color + посчитать количество элементов коллекции IEnumerable класса FlowerMember 
сам класс выглядит так:
public class FlowerMember
{
public int NumberFlower { get; set; }
public string Name {get; set; }
public string Color {get; set; }
}

Comment: так передавайте в модель количество элементов, а не сами элементы. Вам же нужно именно количество указать, не так ли?

Comment: да. каким образом мне это сделать? но мне нужно не только количество. просто мне нужно чтобы был IEnumerable, такое требование.

Comment: извините, я вас не очень понимаю. Как сделать что? Передать количество в модель? Вроде бы тривиальная  задача. Насчет вашего требования передавать IEnumerable в модель - это выглядит странно. Весьма вероятно, что вы как-то неправильно понимаете суть MVC. Я еще раз говорю - гонять с сервера на клиент коллекцию, которая в последствии не используется - это неверно. Если вы используете эту коллекцию где-то еще (не при рендеринге данного представления, а в другом коде, оставшемся за кадром), то это тоже ошибка - значит, вы используете в качестве модели не ту сущность

Comment: Я понимаю суть MVC дело не в этом. Просто у меня такая задача. Да может это и выглядит странно, но мне нужно использовать именно это а не приведенное вами, так как вьюху для вывода, которая находится в папки Areas\Views, Default.cshtml мне менять нельзя. Как сделать в текущем коде, чтобы можно было создать шаблон в папке Shared\DisplayTemplates и использовать его для вывода колллекции Flowers в модели FlowerModel через UIHint или каким-либо другим образом?

Comment: public class FlowerModel
{
 public string FlowerName {get; set; }

 public int Count { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<FlowerModel2> Flowers {get; set; }
}

 public class FlowerModel2
 {
 public string Name {get; set; }

 public string Color { get; set; }
 }

если написать в классе FlowerModel   

public FlowerModel2 Flowers {get; set; } я получаю Name Color

Comment: а если написать IEnumerable<FlowerModel2> Name Color я получить уже не могу ничего не выводится в представлении почему так происходит и как сделать, чтобы Name и Color можно было отобразить в представлении используя IEnumerable<FlowerModel2>?

Comment: допустим если я создаю в модели FlowerModel свойство 

[UIHint("IsActive")]
public bool Active { get; set; }

и создаю в папке Shared\DisplayTemplates шаблон IsActive это работает, а если создаю тоже самое в случае с IEnumerable это не работает

Comment: @Demon извините конечно, но здесь все же не уголок веселых ребусов - к сожалению вы очень бесвязно рассказываете, что вы хотите получить, в чем трудность и почему нельзя обойтись простыми средствами. Я был бы рад вам помочь, но из вашего рассказа довольно сложно понять, что же именно вам нужно, и зачем вы хотите реализовать все это такими (уж простите) черезжопными приемами. Я буду искренне рад помочь вам, если вы четко и ясно расскажете, что вы хотите реализовать, и какие трудности при этом появились. Уж извините, но как передать в модель количество элементов трудностью назвать сложно